# How do I add data from different tables into one new table in mySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

```
CREATE TABLE CU_ORDER

( cordernumber INT PRIMARY KEY, 
fname_lname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
product_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  );

CREATE TABLE TRACKING_NUMBER
    ( trnumber INT PRIMARY KEY
    );

INSERT INTO CU_ORDER VALUES(456, 'John Doe' , Table);
INSERT INTO TRACKING_NUMBER(276734673);
```

I am trying to created a table called Package and in the table it will have all the items from cu_order and all the items from tracking_number. How will I add all of the attributes of this table to one table. What am I doing wrong?

```
CREATE TABLE PACKAGE
( orderno INT PRIMARY KEY, 
fname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
trno INT PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO PACKAGE (........
```

Comment: What is the relation between `cu_order` and `tracking_number`?

Comment: between the two there is no relation I am just adding it to the package. I am new to this, should their be a relation between them?

Answer (score 0):

The two tables do not seem to have a relation, so, *presumably*, you want a cartesian product of both tables. If so, you can use the `insert ... select ...` syntax with a `cross join`:

```
insert into package(orderno, fname, name, trno)
select
    co.cordernumber,
    co.fname_lname,
    co.product_name,
    tn.trnumber 
from cu_order co
cross join tracking_number tn
```

This inserts all possible combinations of rows from both source tables in the target table.

You should also fix the declaration of the `package` table: yours has two primary keys, which is not allowed. Instead, you probably want a compound primary key made of both columns:

```
create table package ( 
    orderno int, 
    fname varchar(50) not null, 
    name varchar(100) not null, 
    trno int,
    primary key(orderno, trno)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new table from the data of another table (or several tables) by appending a SELECT statement to the CREATE TABLE statement.

However, your two source tables are missing the 1:1 relation allowing this to work, which I assume is the cordernumber of CU_ORDER. It appears the table TRACKING_NUMBER is missing a 'cordernumber' column.

```
CREATE TABLE TRACKING_NUMBER (
   trnumber INT PRIMARY KEY,
   cordernumber INT
);
```

After you added the column 'cordernumber' to TRACKING_NUMBER, you can create the new table PACKAGE with:

```
CREATE TABLE PACKAGE (
    orderno INT PRIMARY KEY,
    fname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    trno INT PRIMARY KEY
) 
SELECT
    CU_ORDER.cordernumber AS orderno,
    CU_ORDER.fname_lname AS fname,
    CU_ORDER.product_name AS name,
    TRACKING_NUMBER.trnumber AS trno
FROM CU_ORDER, TRACKING_NUMBER
WHERE CU_ORDER.cordernumber=TRACKING_NUMBER.cordernumber;
```